# Maven Antrun Not Executing Tasks

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using Maven AntRun plugin 1.6 and from their example I cannot code the following ant task to be executed.

Example url: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

I just get the following message when I execute mvn antrun:run. 
No ant target defined - SKIPPED

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                            <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                            <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath" />
                            <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />

                            <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}" />
                            <echo message="runtime classpath: ${runtime_classpath}" />
                            <echo message="test classpath:    ${test_classpath}" />
                            <echo message="plugin classpath:  ${plugin_classpath}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have configured the maven antrun plugin in your `pom.xml`, you only need to call the lifecycle goal configured for the plugin. In this case

`mvn compile`

This will do the needful.

Comment: Thanks!  This was a misunderstanding on how to call the pom.

Comment: An **important** note here (which took me about 1 hour to figure it out): if you use `mvn antrun:run@myexecutionid` and your antrun-target is in a plugin, which resides inside a profile, you **absolutely do need to include the name of the profile in the command line**. E.g.: `mvn -P myprofile antrun:run@myexecutionid`.

Answer (score 25):

try this

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                            <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                            <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath" />
                            <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />

                            <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}" />
                            <echo message="runtime classpath: ${runtime_classpath}" />
                            <echo message="test classpath:    ${test_classpath}" />
                            <echo message="plugin classpath:  ${plugin_classpath}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

note the id

```
<id>default-cli</id>
```

and run the command

```
mvn antrun:run
```

reason for doing this way:
if you don't actually want to "compile", running "mvn compile" to execute something else could be counter productive.

Comment: some hours later of lots of google, this post save my day. thank you. Someone knows why using antrun:run@custom_id doesn't work? `[ERROR] Could not find goal 'run@copy'` <-- in my case the custom_id=copy

Comment: The @ feature was implemented in Maven 3.3.1.  You are likely running an older version.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768